# MongoDB nested array group by Multiple values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a nested array that I want to group according to branch, department, and product. For each of these products, I want to get the sum of the quantity.

This is my array:

```
    const array = [{
      "branch": "Main Office",
      "department": "Accounting",
      "transaction": [{
        "referenceCode": "REF1",
        "product": [{
          "product": "pen",
          "quantity": 5, "color": "blue", "size": 10
        },
        {
          "product": "marker",
          "quantity": 7, "color": "black", "size": 15
        },
        {
          "product": "paper",
          "quantity": 27, "color": "gree", "size": 14
        },
        ]
      },

      {
        "referenceCode": "REF2",
        "product": [{
          "product": "pen",
          "quantity": 3, "color": "brown", "size": 9
        },
        {
          "product": "marker",
          "quantity": 6, "color": "pink", "size": 6
        },
        {
          "product": "paper",
          "quantity": 22, "color": "indigo", "size": 5
        },
        ]
      },
    ],
    },

    {
      "branch": "Sub-office",
      "department": "Warehouse",
      "transaction": [{
        "referenceCode": "REF3",
        "product": [{
          "product": "pen",
          "quantity": 30, "color": "blue", "size": 5
        },
        {
          "product": "marker",
          "quantity": 30, "color": "gold", "size": 34
        },
        ]
      },

      {
        "referenceCode": "REF4",
        "product": [{
          "product": "pen",
          "quantity": 3, "color": "silver", "size": 2
        },
        {
          "product": "marker",
          "quantity": 6, , "color": "white", "size": 3
        },
        {
          "product": "paper",
          "quantity": 30, , "color": "violet", "size": 5
        },
        ]
      },
    ],
    },
  ]
```

This is my desired result:

```
[
    {  "branch": "Main Office",  "department": "Accounting", "product": "pen",  "quantity": 8 },
    {  "branch": "Main Office",  "department": "Accounting", "product": "marker",  "quantity": 13 },
    {  "branch": "Main Office",  "department": "Accounting", "product": "paper",  "quantity": 49 },
    {  "branch": "Sub-office",  "department": "Warehouse", "product": "pen",  "quantity": 33 },
    {  "branch": "Sub-office",  "department": "Warehouse", "product": "marker",  "quantity": 36 },
    {  "branch": "Sub-office",  "department": "Warehouse", "product": "paper",  "quantity": 30 }
  ]
```

I believe the aggregation framework best solves this but I don't know. If there are solutions other than the aggregation framework, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the MongoDB aggregation pipeline with `$group` stage.

### Explanation

1. We flatten `transaction` and `transaction.product` attributes in order to group them
2. We `$group` by `branch`, `department` and `product` values.
3. At the end, we transform into the desired output with the `$replaceRoot` operator.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$transaction"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$transaction.product"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        branch: "$branch",
        department: "$department",
        product: "$transaction.product.product"
      },
      quantity: {
        $sum: "$transaction.product.quantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$_id",
          {
            "quantity": "$quantity"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3QmakIrtKs-)

Comment: I edited my database to include other objects in product. My desired result is still the same as if to ignore "color" and "size". What should I do?

Comment: @LeoGarcia Now, it's very easy to group, check my answer again